# User at end of page sometimes invisible

Tags: bug, status-declined, users, pagination

At the moment writing this I am sharing the same amount of reputation with somebody else in SO. We are last on user page 22 or first on page 23. I was looking for my position, and switching between the two, I sometimes only saw the other person both at the bottom of 22 and the top of 23. Doing it again later, I saw only myself. Seems the sort order or paging algorithm is buggy.

Comment: Easy fix: Just upvote him ;-)

Comment: Jeff, if you are going to decline something, PLEASE say why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took me an awful lot of flipping back and forth between those two pages to reproduce this, but I can at least confirm that this is true.

I would suspect that it should be: `order by reputation desc, username asc`, but maybe it's just doing `order by reputation desc`, in which case, SQL Server will give erratic results in terms of order when that condition is the same.

Comment: I'd do it rep -> length of time on SO.